# use values in the queryset of modelmultiplechoicefield

Tags: django, django-forms

i have a ModelForm like this:

```py
class CustomModelMultipleChoiceField(forms.ModelMultipleChoiceField):

    def label_from_instance(self, obj):
        return obj.get_allowed_user_name


class AddUserToPrivateCourseForm(forms.ModelForm):

    users = CustomModelMultipleChoiceField(queryset=None)

    class Meta:
        model = Course
        fields = [
            'users',
        ]

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields['users'].queryset=User.objects.all()
```

and the method `get_allowed_user_name` in model is

```py
    def get_allowed_user_name(self):
        return "{} {} - {}".format(self.firstname, self.lastname, self.mobile)
```

and the view:

```py
class AddUserToPrivateCourseFormView(CustomUpdateView):
    model = Course
    form_class = AddUserToPrivateCourseForm
    template_name = 'add_user_to_private_course.html'
```

the database has around 60k users and loading this page is very long and takes about half a minute 
so i wanted to instead of capturing everything from db just use `.values()` and take just what is needed for form
so if i use

```py
User.objects.values_list('firstname', 'lastname', 'mobile', 'id')
```

and change `label_from_instance` respectively it works ok and captures and generate what i need but the problem is it is unable to show
already selected users and just shows a list of all users what should be done to generate options
correctly?

Comment: You're using a model form for `Course`, are you initialising your form with the `Course` instance that you want to edit? That should then automatically set the correct initial values for your field.

Comment: Note: I'd suggest something like [django-autocomplete-light](https://django-autocomplete-light.readthedocs.io/en/master/tutorial.html) which provides a better interface for this type of selection (selecting from 60k users by loading them all at once doesn't really seem the right way) and allows you to only query with a filter based on what someone starts typing.

Comment: yes and self.initial does have the corresponding users in __init__ method

Comment: no, you shouldn't use `initial`, you should use `instance`: `form = AddUserToPrivateCourseForm(instance=my_course)`. And setting `self.initial` after the form is initialised in the init method doesn't do anything. By that time the initial values for the fields are already set, so you can only change them by doing `self.fields['some_field'].initial = ...`. but that's not required if you initialise your form with the correct instance.

Comment: yes i am using generic update view and i have edited my question and added it

Comment: then everything should work on your django side of things. If you set a breakpoint inside your form's init method, you'll see that `self.fields['users'].initial` is a set to a list of users. How are you displaying your field?

Comment: i am using javascript select2 field and it worked ok with the `queryset.objects.all()`

Comment: ah of course! you're right, you need to have a list of users, since Django uses the `pk` to set the choices and pre-select the initial values, not dictionaries as you have with `values_list`.

Comment: On your `CustomModelMultipleChoiceField`, add the `def prepare_value(self, value): if isinstance(value, dict): return value['id'] else: return super().prepare_value(value)` method. This would set the correct initial and selection values for your queryset.

Comment: thanks a lot! sily me the problem was with value of options tag